# how to save multiple images in specific folder

Tags: matlab

I want to save all read images into same folder. Here is what I have tried so far:

The problem with the code is I don't know how to save the images.

```
myFolder = 'C:\Users\TheSniper102\Documents\MATLAB\db\3';

filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.bmp');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
  baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);

  img = im2double(imread(fullFileName));
```

I want to save each all images into same folder at path C:\Users\TheSniper102\Documents\MATLAB\newfolder\3

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write image files in matlab using [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) and you can build the path using [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and a loop. Something like this:

```
basePath = 'YOUR/PATH/%d.jpeg'
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)

path = sprintf(basePath,k)
imwrite..
```

.